# Specified cast is not valid.(DBF file)

Tags: .net

i am retrieving data from dbf file when i go for double it goes for **"Specified cast is not valid"** exception even i am writing the related code i.e. **double RNO = dr.GetDouble(0);** RNO is number and in double format in the databse.
can anyone help me.. string is working fine

Comment: `string strCon = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\Users\Najam\Desktop\INT111.DBF ;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=;";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from int111",con);
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                double RNO = dr.GetDouble(0);
                int LINKRNO = dr.GetInt16(1);
                string FORMNO = dr.GetString(2);
                double MRNO = dr.GetDouble(3);} } }`

Comment: Use dr.GetString() then double.Parse() to convert and you should get a more debuggable problem.  I imagine it might be a problem with comma vs decimal point.  Or you're trying to convert DbNull.

Answer (score 0):

As i remember "select * from int111" can return columns in different order but you rely on particalar order. Try to specify columns explicitly like

```
select RNO, LINKRNO, FORMNO, MRNO from int111
```

Comment: thanks buddy i corrected it its type was actually decimal while in database it was showing double.............